# May I flag an answer if it's dangerous and accepted?

Tags: discussion, flags

I found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630734/how-to-invoke-and-control-vibration-using-swift-and-ios8/27278076#27278076) today with two answers. Both answers did work and provided a working solution, but they were different:

- The accepted answer (1 upvote) used a hardcoded integer
- The other answer (9 upvotes) used the recommended constant

I was about to flag the accepted answer, because it may lead people to use a hardcoded value which may change at any time, instead of the recommended (and safe) constant, but before I could hit flag, I just left a comment, that the accepted answer is dangerous and headed over to Meta.

> Flagging is a way of bringing inappropriate content to the attention of the community. The currently implemented flag types are the following: […]

I don't feel comfortable with this answer being accepted and I don't feel comfortable with flagging the answer as `Other (needs ♦ moderator attention)` either.

Comment: Wrong approaches are just *wrong*, not *inappropriate*. Vote, comment, move on.

Comment: You might want to fix your link to point to the answer that is problematic. I was staring at the +12 vote answer and not seeing the issue for a bit longer than I should have.

Comment: As the dangerous one is -3 now, 20k users can delete it. Assuming that it doesn't get undeleted for having some information a mod thinks lacks in the other answer and decides to act on its technical merit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should leave a comment indicating why it's a dangerous answer and downvote it. Once it gets below -0 the community has the opportunity to vote to delete it.

I can't say it enough: Downvotes work wonders and are more powerful than flags.

If there are no competing answers that explain what the right answer is, go ahead and answer the question with the 'right' way.

In this çase; since the accepted answer is the one that's "wrong", there's not much the community can do to delete the post.  It would be up to a moderator to delete it.  The best way to do that is with a custom flag explaining why you think it should be deleted (hint: It's wrong is not a good reason).

Since this is dicey territory, your flag may or may not be declined (Moderators are not arbiters of deciding technical feasibility or correctness of an answer), but one declination won't hurt you.

Comment: One of the main problems is, the accepted answer *is correct*. It's just a dangerous way. I think I'll leave the answer there hopefully being deleted someday. Thank you.